# Manual test cases mapping with Selenium test cases

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, junit4, testng-dataprovider

I have manual test cases written in Excel file with an unique Id associated with each test case.
I have test methods written for these test cases using Selenium Webdriver+TestNG.

I need help on following:
1.How should I map the manual test case Id with automated test cases?
2.I need to run the automated test cases in the order of occurrence of manual test cases.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Apache POI API](http://poi.apache.org/) or [JExcel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to read/write data from MS Excel.

Here is a tutorial of TestNG with JExcel - http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.in/2009/10/dataprovider-data-driven-testing-with.html